# Switch Case Fall Through Scenario

Tags: c, switch-statement, fall-through

So I came upon a competitive question (asking the output) as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        switch(i)
        {
            case 0: i+=5;
            case 1: i+=2;
            case 5: i+=5;
            default: i+= 4;
            break;
        }
        printf("%d ", i);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output is `16, 21`. While I know how switch case works I am unable to explain myself how this fall through works. Why is the default getting added?
Doesn't K&R C book say that the default only executes if none of cases match?
Thanks.

Comment: No, fall-through happens regardless of whether the next case is `default` or not.

Comment: You are not executing default, you are executing some case above which is falling through into default.

Comment: Not sure what the downvote here is for, this is a perfectly reasonable way to read the section of K&R that the OP is referring to, for a beginner. "The case labeled default is executed if none of the other cases are satisfied" sounds exactly like what he was expecting.

Comment: Why is it adding 2 in case 1?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default case is only *jumped to* from the `switch` statement if no other cases match. After one of them has matched, the code executes as if none of the `case` statements existed, unless it hits a `break`. So the `default` case isn't "jumped over" the way you seem to expect.

K & R is a little bit unclear about this, the line you're referring to seems to be:

> If a case matches the expression value, execution starts at that case. All case expressions must be different. The case labeled default is executed if none of the other cases are satisfied

But this is talking about how the `switch` statement *branches*. Fallthrough behavior is on the next page:

> Because cases serve just as labels, after the code for one case is done, execution falls through to the next unless you take explicit action to escape.

which doesn't depend on whether or not there's a `default` case.

The C standard is clearer:

> A switch statement causes control to jump to, into, or past the statement that is the switch body , depending on the  value of a controlling  expression ... If a converted value matches that of the promoted controlling expression, control jumps to the statement following the matched case label. Otherwise, if there is a default label, control jumps to the labeled statement.

Once control jumps, the `case` and `default` labels don't matter anymore.

Comment: Exactly, I got confused in that line.  Thnaks for the explanation, now it's clear to me.

Answer (score 1):

The "body" of `switch` statement is one contiguous linear compound statement. The `case` labels are just that - *labels*, which define different entry points into that contiguous statement. The `default` label is also just a label, no different from `case` labels in that regard.

Once you entered into the `switch` compound statement through a label, the execution will continue in a normal fashion: sequentially all the way to the end of the compound statement (at that stage `case`/`default` labels no longer play any role). If you want to prevent this from happening, it is your responsibility to jump out of that compound statement at the appropriate moment. You can use any jump statement for that, keeping in mind that you also have `break` at your disposal (which is in most cases the most appropriate choice).

In other words, `switch` is not a highly structured branch selector, as it might appear at the first sight. `switch` is just a slightly structured multi-targeted `goto`. All it does is a single run-time parametrised jump. Everything after that jump is your responsibility.

In your code sample you placed a lone `break` at the very end of `switch` compound statement. In that position it actually achieved absolutely nothing, since the compound statement ends there anyway.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "break" included in the switch cases other than default.

When a switch statement is used without breaks, the
code continues executing even after a matching case is found.

Please see below the corrected code :

```
    switch(i)
    {
        case 0: i+=5;
        break;
        case 1: i+=2;
        break;
        case 5: i+=5;
        break;
        default: i+= 4;
        break;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add break statement for every time you need to end that particular case or else it is going to fallthrough all case statements